# Array to Hash with Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I am trying to convert this array:

```
["dog", 5 , "big house"]
```

to hash:

```
{"dog" => 3 , 5 => 25, "big house" => 9}
```

The value will be the number of characters of the string (key). 
If it's an integer (key), then the value will be to the power of 2.

This is what I got so far, but it only converts the string (key):

```
h = {}
arr.each do |x,y|
  y = x.length
  h[x] = y
end
```

Comment: "the power of 2" --Do you mean the second power?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do you get from `2` to `5 => 25`?

Comment: @pangpang Don't change the question.

Comment: @sawa ok, but I think i am right.

Comment: @pangpang You may, but you shouldn't do it. Only the OP should do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
▶ arr = ["dog", 5, "big house"]
#⇒ [ "dog", 5, "big house" ]
▶ arr.zip(arr.map do |e| 
▷     case e
▷     when String then e.length  
▷     when Integer then e ** 2  
▷     else raise 'Neither string nor numeric given'  
▷     end  
▷ end).to_h    
#⇒ { "dog" => 3, 5 => 25, "big house" => 9 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Hash[...]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) constructor to convert an array of [key, value] pairs to a Hash.  So here's another option:

```
arr = ["dog", 5, "big house"]
result = Hash[ arr.map { |e| [e, e.to_i == e ? e**2 : e.length] } ]
# => {"dog"=>3, 5=>25, "big house"=>9}
```

Since Ruby 2, you can use [`Array#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) to do the same thing:

```
result = arr.map { |e| [e, e.to_i == e ? e**2 : e.length] }.to_h
# => {"dog"=>3, 5=>25, "big house"=>9}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Enumberable#each_with_object method like so:

```
array = ["dog",5,"big house"]
array.each_with_object({}) {|x,hash| x.is_a?(String) ? hash[x] = x.length : hash[x] = x**2}
# => {"dog"=>3,5=>25,"big house"=>9}
```

The each_with_object method is very similar to the inject method, so it'll iterate through the array, then once completed it'll return the newly given object. The difference between each_with_object and inject is that each_with_object is immutable, so you can't do something like:

```
(1..5).each_with_object(0) {|num,sum| sum += num}
```

It'll only return a zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) method.

[is_a?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F) method can judge the element is String or Integer.

```
["dog", 2 , "big house"].inject({}) do |sum, e|
  if e.is_a? Integer
    sum.merge({e => e*e})
  elsif e.is_a? String
    sum.merge({e => e.length})
  end
end
=> {"dog"=>3, 2=>4, "big house"=>9}
```

as @Myst said, `h[:key] = value` has better performance than `merge`, so you also can do like this:

```
["dog", 2 , "big house"].inject({}) do |sum, e|
  if e.is_a? Integer
    sum[e] = e*e
  elsif e.is_a? String
    sum[e] = e.length
  end
  sum
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  is_a? is what i was looking for

Comment: This code will result in parsing error. Consider changing `else` to `elsif`.

Comment: @mudasobwa I tried it with Ruby v2.2.2 and it worked fine. Something must've changed, as I'd expect it to error as well.

Comment: @iain I was wrong about an error. Just `else` condition won’t be treated as condition. Try `if false ⏎ puts '' ⏎ else puts 'inside else' ⏎ puts 'another inside' ⏎ end`.

Comment: You are creating too many objects with this code. i.e. `sum.merge({e => e.length})` creates a Hash only to merge it with `sum`. This means that you are creating atlas one unnecessary Hash object with every iteration. You should use `sum[e] = e.length`. I'm sorry for downgrading your answer for such a reason, but this answer might propagate bad practices.

Comment: @Myst your suggestions is quite good，I have learned a lot, thanks!

Comment: @pangpang you're very welcome. Thank you too, both for updating your answer and for your positive feedback.

Comment: @mudasobwa wow, that's really interesting! I suppose some people would be annoyed by this, but it made me laugh and wonder how it could be useful. Perhaps I like Ruby too much :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following array:

```
arr = ["dog", 5, "big house"]
```

First you can create a method to convert elements into your desired format based on the element's class:

```
def convert_to_hash_val(element)
  case element
  when Fixnum
    element**2
  else
    element.size
  end
end
```

Then create an array of `[element, converted_element]` pairs and use the [Hash#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) function to convert this to key, value pairs:

```
Hash[ arr.map {|element| [element, convert_to_hash_val(element)]} ]
# => { "dog" => 3, 5 => 25, "big house" => 9 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr= ["dog", 5, "big house"]
two_dimensional_array =  arr.zip(arr.map do |e| 
  case e
  when String then e.length  
  when Integer then e ** 2  
  else raise 'Neither string nor numeric given'  
  end 
end)

my_hash = Hash[*two_dimensional_array.flatten]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
result_hash = {}
arr = ["dog", 2, "big house"]

arr.each do |el|
  if el.is_a?(String)
    result_hash[el] = el.length
  elsif el.is_a?(Fixnum)
    result_hash[el] = el ** 2
  end
end
```

Remember that the `each` block called on an array only throws one argument into the block, which is the currently iterated element.